# Is there a more stable release of codename one than 6.5.1? or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: codenameone

I am following the book I bought but then also found this pdf after which is way easier than reading on the kindle cloud reader for MAC.... https://www.codenameone.com/files/uber-book/Creating-an-Uber-Clone-In-7-Days-before-sketch.pdf

(I am using both books and haven't ran into any real differences that I saw yet).  As I did the tutorial, it is definitely missing some code to get to this picture, but I just added a counter so each time the **bottom left floating red +** I add a different label.  The action code from the tutorial therefore was modified to

```
private void addNewItem() {
    String str;
    if(counter == 0)
        str = "First Item";
    else if(counter == 1)
        str = "Second Item";
    else
        str = "Third Item";
    counter++;
    TodoItem td = new TodoItem(str, false);
    add(td);
    revalidate();
    td.edit();
}
```

What is very weird is every simulator seems screwed up in that they print First Item but then when clicking a second time, First Item is cleared.  Here is a picture...

[image]

Is there a stable release to use where these simulators work?  OR do others fine 6.5.1 is working just fine and perhaps my environment is somehow whacky.  I have intellij version 2020.1.3.  If anyone knows of a stable release combination, please let me know.

EDIT:
Here is a picture using eclipse and codenameone 6.0.0 with **same exact code**. It works fine in 6.0.0.

[image]

I tried downgrading in intellij but codenameone 6.5(not 6.5.1) is incompatible when I upload the plugin via zip with both intellij 2020.1 and 2020.1.2 and 2020.1.3 AND then I realized it says that.  6.5.1 claimed it was compatible with everything higher than 2016 which was weird so I suspect the issue is I need intellij 2019 actually even with 6.5.1.  Perhaps that is the reason BUT not sure why the simulator would care and act very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how you reached that state. Did you finish the whole tutorial?

Just to be sure I placed the full code of that demo here: https://github.com/codenameone/TodoApp/ I think it should also be in the release source zip.

Comment: THANKS! @Shai Almog though there seems to be no *.java files there?

Comment: Man, you are always so responsive!! Amazing!  I gave more details in the bottom of the post since it's working in eclipse.  Perhaps the release compatibility listed is wrong here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7357-codename-one/versions. I may just use eclipse or downgrade to 2019 intelllij so I can get this to work.  thanks!! I'll keep hacking away it until I get something that works with the tutorial.

Comment: I would recommend IntelliJ and keeping with the latest. Notice that the update in Codename One is a separate thing from the plugin. The plugin itself installs the initial version which we then update using the Codename One Settings/Preferences app (or when you send a build). Part of that update should also replace the designer app. You can see all of that code in the ~/.codenameone directory. You can read about this here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-update-framework.html

Answer (score 0):

The above was missing java files for me so for anyone else, this is the begin of a todo app which is exactly what I needed to get me going.

https://github.com/deanhiller/codenameOneExamples